# Gnome Nanny Questions and some support

Tags: parental-controls

Okay,

So I know this is floating out there for a very long time, and I know this application is still functional.

Before I hear any comments of "set up the computer in an area you can monitor your child" etc, I want to say I am setting up a system for a family member who's child is not mine. I as a parent would want something as simple as content filtering enabled on Ubuntu and linux as a whole so as to block out the most obvious content from a young childs eyes and ears.

Violence, sex, drugs.

Gnome Nanny is able to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and is functional enough.* It specifically does what any parent could want for a content filter, time restriction and even Messaging restriction app (the Messaging Restrictions is not something I'm particularly concerned about though)

What I am looking for is some help on is two distinct items:

1) Does anyone out there know how to build a nanny black list file (.nbl). 
                  I've been able to find a generic one online and install it (this works but I can not determine what specifically is being blocked) This appears to be built from DansGuardian, yet I can find no documentation on how to convert a DG blacklist to a .nbl file.

2) Does anyone know of a way (you'll have to look at the source, and even install Nanny possibly to understand) of how to bring the "Add Blacklisted address" entry box to front? 
                  As it is now this window continually appears behind the main administration pages for Nanny

[Launchpad site for Gnome Nanny](https://launchpad.net/nanny)

I believe this was developed using Pygtk-2.0

Comment: Tools such as gnome nanny take a lot of effort to maintain because web sites change names and no one but you can decide what is appropriate for your children. With that said, most people use tools such as safe search on google and OpenDNS. OpenDNS will fileter sites for you , and it tends to work well with low maintenance. http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/

Comment: Note: all or most of these tools are easily circumvented by determined children.

Comment: I completely understand that these websites can be circumvent by a determined child. Something such as OpenDNS or even Google Safe search do not allow a parent to determine what they would allow their child to read or view as they grow which is why I am interested in Nanny (and such). An alternative as Safe Search on google is just as easily bypass'd by using an alternative search engine. OpenDNS is subject to internet restrictions which many ISP carry, which is ridiculous I know.